# How do I fix the "Cannot source a directory: $HOME/.vimrc" error which pops up when I open GVim?

Tags: vim, gvim

I created the $HOME/.vimrc folder manually. When I delete the folder the error does not appear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.vimrc` is normally a configuration file, not a directory.

The directory name for additional vim/gvim files is called `.vim/`

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but if you're arriving at this post, perhaps you're trying to symlink a `.vimrc` from "dotfiles" directory.  I ran into this error while doing that badly.  This fix for me was to delete the `.vimrc` directory I'd mistakenly symlinked and start over:

$ `ln -s ~/dotfiles/.vimrc ~/.vimrc`